# Getting the heroku build number from environment variables on the cedar stack

Tags: heroku

I noticed that heroku has a build version number i.e. v251 when you deploy to heroku.  Is there any way that I can read that from my application, perhaps an environment variable?  I have a node.js app on their cedar stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, but if you can access the Heroku API you can get it from the Heroku releases.

Answer (score 9):

How about using the [Dyno Metadata](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata).  It looks like the data you need is then just an environment variable away.

Comment: Dyno Metadata does not provide the build ID

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Run `heroku releases` and parse the results into an environment variable on every deploy.